# Marking method availability

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing a library that will be used in various iOS versions. However, some methods will work properly only on the most recent versions of iOS (e.g., iOS 7).

Is there a standard way to mark methods like this in third-party libraries?

Should I use the `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING` macro of Availability.h, or is that best left for Apple methods only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need clang-only, you might consider using the availability attribute:

`void f(void) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.4,deprecated=10.6,obsoleted=10.7)));`

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#availability-attribute

I've found the Availability APIs are kinda old and troublesome to incorporate (heap of `#ifdef`s), whereas the attribute is a more modern and refined way to express availability.